# Can I Dynamic grid row count selected by user per entry?

Tags: grid

I’m trying to allow the author to over ride the default of 7 grid rows to be displayed on main page of article.

I have a drop down filed (limit_override) with “default,25,50,75” to start with.

I would like to have something like this, below does not work

> {if limit_override =="default"}
>
> {grid limit="7"}
>
> {if:else}
>
> {grid  limit="{limit_override}"}
>
> {/if}
>
> stuff...
>
> {/grid}

I have tried stash

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to work this out using something like:

```
{grid_field_name}
    {if limit_override == "default"}
        {if grid_field_name:count <= 7}
            {grid_field_name:grid_col_name}
        {/if}
    {if:else}
        {if grid_field_name:count <= limit_override}
            {grid_field_name:grid_col_name}
        {/if}
    {/if}
{/grid_field_name}
```

Or with Stash you could set_list for the grid output and then get_list with a conditional limit. Or in a separate channel:entries tag get and save the value of limit_override and use that as the limit parameter in the grid field in the main channel:entries. Haven't tested, and not sure which of those 3 ways is the fastest / most efficient.